# Brainteaser - How many sweets must be bad for us to expect 10% of bags to be bad in terms of $X,Y,Z,W$

Tags: probability, statistics

Hi this is a probability question that no one in my math undergrad class could solve. I'm not sure where to start to be honest as its quite different to any probability question I've seen before.

Question: A bag contains a random selection of different sweets.

Some sweets taste "bad" some sweets taste "good".
If one sweet in the bag is "bad" the bag is said to be "bad". There are X number of different sweets.

There are Y number of bags.
On average a sweet appears in Z number of different bags. On average there are W number of different sweets to a bag.

How many sweets must be bad for us to expect 10% of bags to be bad in terms of X,Y,Z,W?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please don't intentionally duplicate questions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the feed back :) I'll give it a read and try to repost. Is there anything in particular you thought was wrong with how the question was phrased. Im new to the community and its frustrating that my questions keep getting closed. Thanks again!